# Proving a sequence defined by a certain recurrence relation is always a square.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Prove that

$$a_{n+3} = \frac{(n^2 + n + 1) (n + 1)}{n}a_{n+2} + (n^2 + n + 1)a_{n+1} - \frac{n+1}{n}a_n$$

With $a_0 = 0$, $a_1 = 1$, $a_2=0$, $a_3 = 1$ is always a square.

From explicit terms it looks like for even n, $a(n)$ is divisible by $n$. I don't know if that is useful or even true.

The problem is from "Problems in Analysis: Advanced Calculus on the Real Axis" by Teodora-Liliana T. Radulescu, Vicentiu D. Radulescu, and Titu Andreescu

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: one thing you get from finding explicit terms is this:  you may find out a likely recurrence for $\sqrt {a_n} ,$  see if you can prove about that

Comment: @person FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a_%7Bn%2B3%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7B(n%5E2%2Bn%2B1)(n%2B1)%7D%7Bn%7Da_%7Bn%2B2%7D%2B(n%5E2%2Bn%2B1)a_%7Bn%2B1%7D-%5Cfrac%7Bn%2B1%7D%7Bn%7Da_n%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Asquare&p=1), your recursion equation is in [Does this sequence consist of squares of integers?](/q/874873) and [$x_{n + 3} = \frac{(n + 1)(n^2 + n + 1)}{n}x_{n + 2} + (n^2 + n + 1)x_{n + 1} - \frac{n + 1}{n}x_n, n \ge 1$, $\sqrt{x_n} \in \mathbb N, n \ge 0$.](/q/3531405), but only the first one uses the same initial conditions as yours.